# Question regarding an algebraic manipulation in GFology

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, proof-explanation

[image]

How does the author arrive at the last equality in the first line, i.e.$$\text{why is } [x^k]\frac{1}{1-y(1+x)} = \frac{1}{1-y}[x^k]\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)x} \text{?}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author factorised the denominator.

$$\left(1-y\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)x\right) = 1-y-yx = 1-y(1+x)$$

The coefficient of $x^k$ is unaffected by factoring out a function of $y$.